# Why does the HTMLInputElement's `list` field only have a getter, and no setter?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, deno, ts-node

I'm creating an HTMLInputElement in Typescript, which I intend to use as a "slider" by setting the input element's `type` field to `"range"`.

According to MDN Web Docs, I can make this slider fancier by creating an instance of an HTMLDatalistElement, giving the datalist an `id`, and referencing the datalist's `id` via the slider's `list` field. This will not only give my slider some tick marks to denote where the slider cursor is currently located, but I can then set the datalist's HTMLOptionElement's `label` field to introduce labelled tick marks.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#adding_labels

However, Deno/TS-Node complains with this error:

```
error: TS2540 [ERROR]: Cannot assign to 'list' because it is a read-only property.
      inputElement.list = datalistId;
```

and Google Chrome complains with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property list of #<HTMLInputElement> which has only a getter
```

Since the MDN Web Docs clearly show that this fields is meant to be used, I attempted to silence the Deno/TS-Node error by ignoring it via:

```
// @ts-ignore
```

This solution did not work, and resulted in the above Google Chrome runtime error.

I don't understand why this field is allowed to be set when constructing an HTMLInputElement via an `.html` file, but you aren't allowed to use it when creating an instance of an HTMLInputElement dynamically via Javascript/Typescript. Being able to dynamically set a slider's tick mark labels would be very nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element), the `list` [*content* attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-attributes) is indeed specified to contain the ID of a corresponding `datalist` element:

> The `list` attribute is used to identify an element that lists predefined options suggested to the user.
> If present, its value must be the ID of a `datalist` element in the same tree.

However, the `input` element's `list` *IDL* attribute (as specified in the DOM interface) is read-only, and returns the actual `HTMLDataListElement` instead of its ID:

> ```
> interface HTMLInputElement : HTMLElement {
>   // ...
>   readonly attribute HTMLDataListElement? list;
>   // ...
> }
> ```

You can, however, manipulate the `list` *content* attribute using the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) function, and set the `datalist` ID on the `input` element that way:

```js
document.querySelector('#input').setAttribute('list', 'values');
```

```html
<input id="input" type="range">
<datalist id="values">
  <option value="0" label="0"></option>
  <option value="50" label="50"></option>
  <option value="100" label="100"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Might be good to stress out the difference between IDL attributes (`.list`) and content attributes (`list="...">`). Some do map to each other, but many don't, like this one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between an attribute in HTML `<tag attribute="value">`, and an attribute of that an [`Element`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element).

The attributes retrieved from the HTML are stored in `NamedNodeMap attributes;`  and can be controlled using e.g. `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.

The attribute an DOM Elements (that inherit from `Element`) do not need (even if they have the same name) to have the same value, their value is derived from the [`Attr`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#attr) stored in `attributes`.

If you take a look at this example, you can see that there is a difference in behavior depending on which one you manipulate and retrieve:

```js
document.getElementById('test1').setAttribute('value','html-value')

document.getElementById('test2').setAttribute('value','html-value')
document.getElementById('test2').value = 'js-value'

document.getElementById('test3').value = 'js-value'
console.log(document.getElementById('test3').getAttribute('value'))
```

```css
[value="html-value"] {
  color: red;
}

[value="js-value"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
Test1:
<input id="test1">
Test2:
<input id="test2">
Test3:
<input id="test3">
```

So for `list` the attribute of the DOM Element is created based on what is set for the Attribute `Node` with the name list (which is an ID).

The `list` attribute of the DOM Element is probably set to readonly which contains a list of elements, because that list could not be mapped back to an ID.